# bootstrap swipe not working with anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel, swipe

I am using the TouchSwipe plugin for my carousel swipe effect.

The problem is that swipe does not work when I enclose the image or content within

```
<a href=""></a>
```

I tried assigning them z-index but still it does not work.

I even tried their example and tried the same things using inspect element.

http://lazcreative.com/bs3/touchswipe.html

This is the script :-

```
$('#carousel-example-generic-myslider').swipe( {
    swipeLeft: function() {
        $(this).carousel('next');
    },
    swipeRight: function() {
        $(this).carousel('prev');
    },
    allowPageScroll: 'vertical'
});
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Is this id (#carousel-example-generic-myslider) is referred to the anchor tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For touchswipe, there is an option 'excludedElements' which is defaulted to `"button, input, select, textarea, a, .noSwipe"`. So 'a' tags will be excluded from the swipe event. You need to remove that 'a' reference from that.

Try this initialization, for eg:

```
$('#carousel-example-generic-myslider').swipe( {
    swipeLeft: function() {
        $(this).carousel('next');
    },
    swipeRight: function() {
        $(this).carousel('prev');
    },
    allowPageScroll: 'vertical',
    excludedElements: "button, input, select, textarea, .noSwipe"

});
```

Comment: no it did not work. I added a tag also in that exclude statement but still no change

Comment: dont add 'a' tag u should remove the 'a' tag from the excluded elements

Comment: ya, i tried what u gave - exactly - but no change. then i tried adding - still not working

Comment: I was trying to understand this excludedElements because it was exactly the opposite of what I wanted with the 'a' elements. For clearing this out for anyone as tired as I am, The list of elements in the "excludedElements" in this answer is just like the plugin default one WITHOUT the 'a' element. (sorry for being Captain Obvious here ;)